# datagridview does not update edit changes

Tags: datagridview, contenteditable

Im building an bulk insert app to transfer data between Excel to Sql Server in windows forms .net 3.5
The problem is that sometimes excel data need some changes before go to Sql Server, thats why I need create an application with editable datagridview that works like intermediate layer in the process.

The application consist in take an excel contents in one datagridview, then I do some validations using backcolor changes, tooltips, etc. So If there are some cells with validations, the user press F2 and changes the respective content.

The problem is that when the user ends to change the cell, I want apply again the validation procedure (change backcolor rows, add tooltips, etc) and this does not work anymore, just worked once. In other words, after some changes in datagridview cells, any method for change backcolor of cells does not work.

Some ideas? Thanks everyone.

Note:

This is one of my 4 validate methods:

```
**enter code here**

Public Sub Validate()
    For Each x As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(0).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(1).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(2).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(3).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(4).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(5).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If


        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(6).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(6).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(7).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If


        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(8).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(8).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(9).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(9).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(10).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(10).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(11).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(11).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(12).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(12).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If


        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(13).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(13).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(14).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(14).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(15).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(15).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(16).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(16).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(17).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(17).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End If



        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(18).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(18).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(19).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(19).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
        If IsDBNull(x.Cells(20).Value) Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x.Index).Cells(20).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at your RowDataBound event, and applying your coloring changes there.

```
    protected void DataGridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   Validate() 'add any other coloring changes here as well
}
```

What this will do is force the coloring changes to take place every time the rows get rebound (which is after every change to the datagrid - unfortunately they aren't the most efficient components out there)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I use windows forms.

Comment: In this case, look into the OnRowLeave event, and call the methods there as it will fire off whenever someone clicks on the next row, or another control in the form, including before they click on a button, etc.